# issue with smooth transition when div is sliding up

Tags: css, transition, smoothing

Hi I have 2 divs (one on top of each other)contained within a parent div. on hover I want the top div to slide u and reveal the red div below it. I have sort of got it working though it does not transition smoothly and flashes when I move the mouse around. I want it to hold the position until the mouse leaves the div area then smoothly slide back down to its original position. I have added the code and jsfiddle below. I Would really appreciate your help and input!

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"> Testing</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .block{
  height:304px;
  width:304px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .top{
   top: 0;
   height:300px;
   width:300px;
   border: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
 }

 .top:hover{
  margin-top: -304px; 
  display: block;  
  -webkit-transition:.43s ease;
  -moz-transition:.43s ease;
  -ms-transition:.43s ease;      
 }


.bottom{
  color: #f8f8f8;  
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: #CF222D;
  border: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
 }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gBk2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this happen because the hover styles are applied only when you are hovering over the `.top` element. As the transition takes place, the hit-area of the `.top` element is reduced, and replaced by the `.bottom` element.. once the `.bottom` element expands to where your mouse is located, the CSS no longer sees that you are hovering over the `.top` element, and reverses the transition. You get the flicker as the styles fight, constantly going back and forth over the point where your mouse is located.

You should apply the hover styles by checking the state of the parent element, like so:

```
.block:hover .top {  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4gBk2/5/

**Edit:**

As a side note, you should also put your `transition` styling just inside of the `.top{ }` selector, as this will ensure proper up and down sliding motions. (this is a good practice, as it means the transition is always present, and not only being applied at the same time it is being ran)

here's an alternate example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4gBk2/6/

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation of this, I have a much better understanding about how it works now. I was just about to mention that I figured out how to slide it down smoothly by moving the transitions up to the .top !